# For /f loop with delims to split and use a string only runs once(batch)

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

So I have a list of dates which can be any amount in theory like this separated by and underscore in a string format.

I would like to split this string and use it within a for loop with further code but when echo ing only the first date is printed i.e 02/03/2020 in this case.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
@Echo off
Set dates=02/03/2020_03/04/202_04/04/2020
for /f "delims=_" %%b in ("%dates%") do (
Echo %%b
)
```

I also tried using tokens just to see what would happen and this code below printed more than one but as I don't know how many dates that isn't practical for me

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%b in ("%dates%") do (
Echo %%b
Echo %%c
```

And finally I also tried using 1* in the tokens section but that just returned the string as it is without being delimited at all

Any advise for what I may be doing wrong here would be very appreciated

Comment: The `for /F` loop iterates once per *line* of text; it does not iterate through all the tokens that are extracted of a single line, they are all returned (by `%%b`, `%%c`, etc.) in the same iteration. You could however use a standard `for` loop: `for %%A in (%dates:_= %) do echo %%A` (first, each `_` becomes replaced by a _space_, then the loop iterates through the space-separated items)

Comment: The FOR loop sees the `%dates%` variable as a single string because it is quoted. Try it without using QUOTATION MARK characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In batch scripting, variables are assigned using the `Set` xommand. open cmd and type `set /?`

Additionally, tokens / delims is unecessary. Use substring modification to replace `_` with a standard delimiter.

```bat
@Set "dates=02/03/2020_03/04/2020_04/04/2020"
@For %%G in (%Dates:_= %)Do @Echo/%%G
```

Comment: I took this advise and swapped out the delimiter for spaces and a regular for and that did the trick, thank you!